# How to create an integer, json-schema, validation rule that validates an integer is not equal to 0(zero)?

Tags: jsonschema

I would like to validate an integer value (property) on not being 0(zero).
Positive and negative integers are allowed, except 0.

Comment: can you post your JSON structure? you can just validate the integer by using != operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `not` `enum`: `{"type":"integer", "not":{"enum":[0]}}`.

Or `not` `const` with recent JSON Schema revision: `{"type":"integer", "not":{"const":0}}`